# Looking for a good sample working code for downloading any file from URL in flutter. If its with native downloader then this will be very good

Tags: flutter

Looking for a good sample working code for downloading any file from URL in flutter. If its with native downloader then this will be very good. Please help me with sample of code to download any file using native downloader in flutter.

I have used few libraries but didn't turned out well.

Comment: Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the flutter_downloader plugin? [https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader)

Comment: Yes but its giving me a error.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error you are receiving? What code have you written so far to try and build a working example?

Answer (score 1):

For a mobile device, I used the `http` package to download a file to the applications document directory

First, create a httpClient object

```
static var httpClient = new HttpClient();
```

Then you can create a function like this to download the file:

```
Future<void> _downloadFile({
    required String fileName,
  }) async {
    String url = ...;
    var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = await request.close();
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory())!.path;
    File file = new File('$dir/$fileName'); // Note: Filename must contain the extension of the file too, like pdf, jpg etc.
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  }
```

For a flutter web application, I felt the `url_launcher` package was the easiest to work with.

```
_launchURL() async {
    String url = ...;
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
      print('URL Launcher success');
    } else {
      throw Exception('Could not launch $url');
    }
  }
```

The url_launcher package code works even for a mobile device but it opens a new browser window to download the required file which is not a good user experience so I have used 2 approaches for the same problem.

Hope I have answered your query.